# image not available in mysql when upload with codeigniter

Tags: image, codeigniter

1. Problem:
   When try to store an image in MySql database field (BLOB) through codeigniter service, the image is not enabled in mysql. (I know is not a good practice but requirement). When is upload the image through mysl admin, image its ok.
2. How do i test?
   I use postman with several text fields and one "file" field where i take the image to be stored in database.

[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaDJx.png)

3. Results of test:
   All  "text" fields are stored in database, the "file" field is uploaded to a directory as expected but the bynary data is not stored in database in field "foto"

[Results in MySql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1Aa8.png)

4. Code in Codeigneter:

```html
public function CrearCliente(){
    $user = $this->input->post('user');
    $nombre = $this->input->post('nombre');
    $apellido = $this->input->post('apellido');
    $rut = $this->input->post('rut'); 
    $correo = $this->input->post('correo');
    $id_pais = $this->input->post('id_pais');
    $fecha = $this->input->post('creacion');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');
    $presentacion = $this->input->post('presentacion'); 
    $telefono = $this->input->post('telefono'); 
    $long = 0;
    $lat = 0;
    $res="null";
  $this->load->library('form_validation');
  $mimetypes = array("image/jpeg", "image/pjpeg", "image/gif", "image/png");
  $foto = $_FILES['foto']['name'];
  $tamanio = $_FILES['foto']["size"];
  $archivo = $_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'];
  $type = $_FILES['foto']['type'];
  $imagen = fopen($archivo, 'rb');
    $contenido2 = fread($imagen, $tamanio);
   $contenido=file_get_contents($archivo,TRUE);
  $contenido3 = $this->db->escape_str($contenido);
   fclose($imagen);
  if(!in_array($type, $mimetypes))
               die("El archivo que subiste no es una imagen válida");
                          
  $config['upload_path'] = './imagenes/';
  $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
  $config['max_size'] = '5000000';
  $config['quality'] = '90%';
  $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
  $config['max_width']            = 1024;
    $config['max_height']           = 768;
  $config['file_name'] = $foto;
  $this->load->library('upload', $config);
  if (!$this->upload->do_upload('foto')) {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $data['uploadError'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
        die('error');
                }
  else{
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
          }
  
    $this->load->model('Usuario');
    $res = $this->Usuario->InsertUsuario($contenido3,$user, $nombre, $apellido,$rut, $correo, $foto,$tamanio,$id_pais,$fecha,$password,$presentacion,$telefono,$long,$lat);   // *se le asigna una variable al modelo para guardar el contenido que retorna la bd
    header('content-type: application/json'); //* se colcoa una cabezera para decir que se va a retornar un Json
    echo json_encode($res);  
   }




function InsertUsuario($contenido,$user, $nombre, $apellido,$rut, $correo, $foto,$tamanio,$id_pais,$fecha,$password,$presentacion,$telefono,$long,$lat)
   {
   
     $hoy=getdate();   
     if ($foto) {
       echo $contenido;
       
      }
    else{
       $imagen = null;
       header('content-type: application/json');
       echo json_encode("./upload/error.jpg");
    }   
     $this->db->trans_strict(TRUE);
     $this->db->trans_start();   
     $data = array(
         'user'          =>   $user,
         'nombre'          =>   $nombre,
         'apellido'          =>   $apellido,
         'id_rut'          =>   $rut,
         'correo'          =>   $correo,
         'foto'          =>   $contenido,
         'id_pais'          =>   $id_pais,
         'password'          =>   $password,
         'presentacion'  =>    $presentacion,
         'telefono'  =>    $telefono,
         'creacion'          =>   $fecha,
         'long'          =>   $long,
         'lat'          =>   $lat
         );
  
         $this->db->insert('wm_clientes',$data);
         $this->db->trans_complete();
         if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
             {
               return $res='ERROR';
             }
             else
             {
               return $res='OK';
             }
   }
```

5. Question: Why the data related to image (jpg) file is not storing in database? Check image. I tried a lot of things but seen to be more difficult i expected. Need help gurus!
   **strong text**

Comment: can u recieve the image data ???

Comment: yes i think, because when make echo $image bring some characters

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function CrearCliente() {
    $user = $this->input->post('user');
    $nombre = $this->input->post('nombre');
    $apellido = $this->input->post('apellido');
    $rut = $this->input->post('rut');
    $correo = $this->input->post('correo');
    $id_pais = $this->input->post('id_pais');
    $fecha = $this->input->post('creacion');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');
    $presentacion = $this->input->post('presentacion');
    $telefono = $this->input->post('telefono');
    $long = 0;
    $lat = 0;
    $res = "null";
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $mimetypes = array("image/jpeg", "image/pjpeg", "image/gif", "image/png");
    $foto = $_FILES['foto']['name'];
    $tamanio = $_FILES['foto']["size"];
    $archivo = $_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'];
    $type = $_FILES['foto']['type'];
    //$imagen = fopen($archivo, 'rb');
    //$contenido2 = fread($imagen, $tamanio);
    //fclose($imagen);
    if (!in_array($type, $mimetypes)) {
        // ci upload checks mimes for you
        show_error("El archivo que subiste no es una imagen válida");
    }

    $config['upload_path'] = './imagenes/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '5000000';
    $config['quality'] = '90%';
    $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
    $config['max_width'] = 1024;
    $config['max_height'] = 768;
    $config['file_name'] = $foto;
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('foto')) {
        //$error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        //$data['uploadError'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
        show_error($this->upload->display_errors());
    }
    $contenido = file_get_contents($this->upload->data('full_path'));
    $contenido3 = $this->db->escape_str($contenido);
    $this->load->model('Usuario');
    $res = $this->Usuario->InsertUsuario($contenido3, $user, $nombre, $apellido, $rut, $correo, $foto, $tamanio, $id_pais, $fecha, $password, $presentacion, $telefono, $long, $lat);   //  *se le asigna una variable al modelo para guardar el contenido que retorna la bd
    header('content-type: application/json'); //* se colcoa una cabezera para decir que se va a retornar un Json
    echo json_encode($res);
}

function InsertUsuario($contenido, $user, $nombre, $apellido, $rut, $correo, $foto, $tamanio, $id_pais, $fecha, $password, $presentacion, $telefono, $long, $lat) {

    $hoy = getdate();
    if ($foto) {
        echo $contenido;
    } else {
        $imagen = null;
        header('content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode("./upload/error.jpg"); // this doesn't seem valid, also you should probably exit
    }
    // no need for transaction when only running 1 query
    $this->db->trans_strict(TRUE);
    $this->db->trans_start();
    $data = array(
        'user' => $user,
        'nombre' => $nombre,
        'apellido' => $apellido,
        'id_rut' => $rut,
        'correo' => $correo,
        'foto' => $contenido,
        'id_pais' => $id_pais,
        'password' => $password,
        'presentacion' => $presentacion,
        'telefono' => $telefono,
        'creacion' => $fecha,
        'long' => $long,
        'lat' => $lat
    );
    $this->db->insert('wm_clientes', $data);
    $this->db->trans_complete();
    if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE) {
        return $res = 'ERROR';
    } else {
        return $res = 'OK';
    }
}
```

---

I would also suggest sending the array of data to the insert function instead of each as a parameter - it is messy and confusing and prone to errors. I also wouldn't suggest mixing string return types with json return types as it is an inconsistent interface. Also if you are using ajax you need to use `FormData` or a plugin to upload a file in case you weren't.

Comment: Hi Alex, the image is not storing in database with your changes, same issue, Thanks for suggetions, i will take it.

Comment: In the insert fuction can you verify you are getting the file by echoing it's variable? Let me know result. Also make sure error reporting is on and db debug in config file and then see if any errors are occuring. Please also verify the image is actually uploading.

Comment: File is getting bacause seen something like (����\0JFIF\0\0\0...) when echoing.Where i can check $config['log_threshold'] =0 i change to 4,  and db debug can not find in config.php.

Comment: When i query "select foto from wm_clientes", results are [[BLOB - 121.7 KB]]
[[BLOB - 5 KB]]
[[BLOB - 4.4 KB]]
[[BLOB - 4.8 KB]]
[[BLOB - 3.7 KB]]
[[BLOB - 4.3 KB]]
[[BLOB - 3.7 KB]]
[[BLOB - 6.3 KB]]
[[BLOB - 7.2 KB]]

Comment: sorry db debug is in database.php and log_threshold of 1 is fine. can you share a picture of the database schema page ("structure")

Comment: Debug is 'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production').

Comment: yes you can just make it true instead of `(ENVIRONMENT !== 'production')`

Comment: wait... you are getting the blob tho? thought you said you weren't "[[BLOB - 121.7 KB]] [[BLOB - 5 KB]] [[BLOB - 4.4 KB]] [[BLOB - 4.8 KB]] [[BLOB - 3.7 KB]] [[BLOB - 4.3 KB]] [[BLOB - 3.7 KB]] [[BLOB - 6.3 KB]] [[BLOB - 7.2 KB]]"

Comment: Structure is:  1 ID_CLIENTEPrimariaÍndice int(11)   No Ninguna  AUTO_INCREMENT  Cambiar Cambiar  Eliminar Eliminar 

 8 FOTO mediumblob   No Ninguna    Cambiar Cambiar  Eliminar Eliminar 
Más Más

Comment: Yes, the BLOB i receive can not be viewed through MySQL. Check image attached. If i upload image with phpadmin, no problem

Comment: 1) but have you tried actually outputting it to see? 2) are you using the **same** image to test? 3) maybe you should use `longblob` instead  of just `blob`

Comment: i use mediumblob, when i take same image to try to store with codeigniter code, the data stores in the field is seen like [BLOB-7.2 KB] but when i upload with phpadmin in mysql, the field seen as a image.

Comment: I get that too (no image in phpmyadmin) but that doesn't mean there is anything wrong with the data. I suggest you try outputting it. If that doesn't work switch to longblob and try again. Example test script that also outputs: https://pastebin.com/buhCawA7

Comment: i tested with your code, any image, and the image loaded by codeigniter outputted wrong, but the others are outputted ok.

Comment: did you try changing to `longblob`? my best guess is the image binary size is too large for the field so it is getting corrupted - irregardless you should always verify it is working not by a thumbnail in phpmyadmin but by actually seeing its output. i also don't get why you are saving the file locally and in the db. typically blobs aren't used for because they are a PITA and not so efficient as a local file.

Comment: i change to longblob but same result. Do you think can be by addtional convertion? look, i make a manual update of the image in phpadmin and codeigniter make the next sentence (UPDATE `wm_clientes` SET `FOTO` = 0xffd8ffe000104a46494600010100000100010000ffdb00840009060...)

Comment: sorry, codeigneter does not, i mean mysql in previous paragrah

Comment: I personally think php and phpmyadmin probably have different ways of doing it. Ultimately I cannot explain it as with my test file I uploaded it worked for me and for you it hasn't. If I can't replicate the issue I'm not of much help.

Answer (score 0):

Any easy way around this would be to just store the image on your server (which you are doing already with your code) and then save the image name to your database as a varchar.

```
$config['upload_path'] = './imagenes/';
```

Above is the code that is uploading it to your server. It goes to that path on your server using the upload library provided by codeigniter.

You can now query your database for the image name, rather than the actual image, and use that in your view in an image tag. This will pull the image from the server.

If you have any questions about this method let me know.